# SGD converges but batch learning does not, simple regression in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have run into an issue where batch learning in tensorflow fails to converge to the correct solution for a simple convex optimization problem, whereas SGD converges. A small example is found below, in the Julia and python programming languages, I have verified that the same exact behaviour results from using tensorflow from both Julia and python.

I'm trying to fit the linear model `y = s*W + B` with parameters `W` and `B`
The cost function is quadratic, so the problem is convex and should be easily solved using a small enough step size. If I feed all data at once, the end result is just a prediction of the mean of `y`. If, however, I feed one datapoint at the time (commented code in julia version), the optimization converges to the correct parameters very fast.

I have also verified that the gradients computed by tensorflow differs between the batch example and summing up the gradients for each datapoint individually.

Any ideas on where I have failed?

```
using TensorFlow

s = linspace(1,10,10)
s = [s reverse(s)]
y = s*[1,4] + 2
session = Session(Graph())

s_ = placeholder(Float32, shape=[-1,2])
y_ = placeholder(Float32, shape=[-1,1])

W = Variable(0.01randn(Float32, 2,1), name="weights1")
B = Variable(Float32(1), name="bias3")

q =    s_*W + B
loss = reduce_mean((y_ - q).^2)
train_step = train.minimize(train.AdamOptimizer(0.01), loss)

function train_critic(s,targets)
    for i = 1:1000
        # for i = 1:length(y)
        #     run(session, train_step, Dict(s_ => s[i,:]', y_ => targets[i]))
        # end
        ts = run(session, [loss,train_step], Dict(s_ => s, y_ => targets))[1]
        println(ts)
    end
    v = run(session, q, Dict(s_ => s, y_ => targets))
    plot(s[:,1],v, lab="v (Predicted value)")
    plot!(s[:,1],y, lab="y (Correct value)")
    gui();
end

run(session, initialize_all_variables())
train_critic(s,y)
```

Same code in python (I'm not a python user so this might be ugly)

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn.datasets
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import reset_default_graph

s = np.linspace(1,10,50).reshape((50,1))
s = np.concatenate((s,s[::-1]),axis=1).astype('float32')
y = np.add(np.matmul(s,[1,4]), 2).astype('float32')

reset_default_graph()
rng = np.random
s_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])

weight_initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1)
with tf.variable_scope('model'): 
    W = tf.get_variable('W', [2, 1], 
                          initializer=weight_initializer)
    B = tf.get_variable('B', [1], 
                          initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

q = tf.matmul(s_, W) + B

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(y_ , q)))


optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

num_epochs = 200

train_cost= []
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)
    for e in range(num_epochs):
        feed_dict_train = {s_: s, y_: y}
        fetches_train = [train_op, loss]
        res = sess.run(fetches=fetches_train, feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
        train_cost = [res[1]]
        print train_cost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that when I fed in the targets, I fed a vector and not an Nx1 matrix. The operation `y_-q` then turned into a broadcast operation and instead of returning the elementwise difference, it returned an `NxN` matrix with the desired difference along the diagonal. In Julia, I solved this by modifying the line

`train_critic(s,y)`
to
`train_critic(s,reshape(y, length(y),1))`

to ensure `y` being a matrix.

A subtle error that took me a very long time to find! Part of the confusion was that TensorFlow seems to treat vectors as row vectors and not as column vectors like Julia, hence the broadcast operation in `y_-q`